# Recycler view does not show any thing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i checked several times but i don't i understand why does not show item
it just show  blank Space that was for Recycler view 
i used log method every where and every thing is normal in log  but i can't get 
result
it's my main activity that i called adapter and build my array list in it and call 5 item

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        interviews();
    }

    private void interviews() {
        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.rcl_orders);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        OrderAdapter orderAdapter =new OrderAdapter(this,getOrders());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<Orders> getOrders(){
        ArrayList<Orders> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(new Orders(1,1," NewYork City"));
        orders.add(new Orders(2,2,"Masochist"));
        orders.add(new Orders(3,1,"San francisco"));
        orders.add(new Orders(4,5,"pennsylvania"));
        orders.add(new Orders(5,3,"LosAngeles"));

        return orders;
    }

}
```

it's my model 
i build a model in this class and setter and getter are made and when i log that variables they are full and correct

```
public class Orders {
    private int kind,count ;
    private String address;

    public Orders() {
    }

    public int getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(int kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Orders(int kind, int count, String address) {
        this.kind = kind;
        this.count = count;
        this.address = address;

    }
}
```

it's my adapter

```
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Orders> orders;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Orders> orders) {
        this.context=context;
        this.orders=orders;
    }


    @Override
    public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ordercity,null);
        OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder =new OrderViewHolder(view);
        return orderViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( OrderViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Orders order = orders.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText("set text ");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("MainActtivity","value"+ orders.size());
        return (orders == null ? 0 : orders.size());
    }
}
```

and it's my view holder

```
public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public CheckBox Selected;
    public OrderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_order);
        Selected=itemView.findViewById(R.id.chk_selected);
    }
}
```

pleaze help me!!!

Comment: can you show your layout resource `R.layout.ordercity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your `onCreateViewHolder()`:**

**Change this:**

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ordercity,null);
```

**To this:**

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ordercity , parent , false);
```

Comment: it's works but its show 5 recyclerview instead of 5 item in recyclerview

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rcl_orders">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>

Comment: Try to make the height of recycler view `match_parent`? Other than that your problem is solved for not showing items. You can ask a new question for other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Update in your adapter like below

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("MainActtivity","value"+ orders.size());
        return orders.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
@Override
    public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ordercity,null);
        OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder =new OrderViewHolder(view);
        return orderViewHolder;
    }



@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("MainActtivity","value"+ orders.size());
        return (orders == null ? 0 : orders.size());
    }
```

**To**

```
@Override
        public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.ordercity, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}



 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("MainActtivity","value"+ orders.size());
        return orders.size());
    }
```